# Why is my mesh black in material mode?

Tags: texturing

I am very new at blender and I must have made some weird mistake. I already have a texture on my mesh (which you can see in render mode) but when I go into material mode my mesh turns black. The texture was working on the mesh until one day when I opened up the file and it was black. If someone could help it would be greatly appreciated[here is the link to the blender file http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=48437](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=48437)

Comment: Please use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for blend files.

Comment: I just opened the file and everything looks good on my computer. If you try opening the exact file you posted does the texture still appear black?

Comment: @Brenticus I did what you said and when I opened the file it was fine again! Thank you so much!